# $f(w)=\frac{w}{4w^{2}-1}$, find max value of $|f(w)|$ in $|w|\geq1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(w)=\frac{w}{4w^{2}-1}$, find max value of $|f(w)|$ in $|w|\geq1$

What I have done is $$|f(w)|=\left|\frac{w}{4w^{2}-1}\right|=\left|\frac{w\overline{w}}{(4w^{2}-1)\overline{w}}\right|=\left|\frac{|w|}{4w|w|-\overline{w}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{4w-\overline{w}}\right|$$How can I keep simplifying it to use $|w|=1$?

Comment: I sense that $w = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ might be interesting. Or do you mean $\lvert w\rvert = 1$ rather than $\leq 1$ as you have written twice?

Comment: @DanielFischer He does mean $|w|=1$.

Comment: Because by maximum modulus principle, |f(w)| have max value only on the boundary, i.e. |w|=1

Comment: @user133140 There's an ingredient of the maximum modulus principle missing here.

Comment: I am so sorry, the region should be |w|≥1

Comment: Okay. But usually, the maximum modulus principle is stated about bounded domains, while $\lvert w\rvert \geqslant 1$ is unbounded. Why does the maximum modulus principle nevertheless work here (or maybe it doesn't? Are you _sure_ it does?)?

Comment: I think it should be true, since it is a exercise after the principle in my text book, and the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

You already showed that $|f(w)|=|\frac{1}{4w-\overline{w}}|$ To maximize this, we should minimize $|4w-\overline{w}|$. Geometrically, this is achieved if $w$ and $\overline{w}$ point in the same direction, i.e., $4w=\lambda\overline{w}$, with $\lambda>0$. We see that $w=1$ and the maximum is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Is there any way that I can insert |w|=1 to it directely?

Comment: Yes, you denote $w=e^{i\theta}$ and $\overline{w}=e^{-i\theta}$, and so it is possible to calculate $(4w-\overline{w})\overline{(4w-\overline{w})}$, but that is a bit of work.

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maximum Modulus principle applies when the function is analytic in the disk, but it has poles at $\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

You could try parameterizing $|w|=1$ as $e^{i\theta}$, then expressing $|f(z)|$ as a real function of a real variable, then employ standard calculus techniques.

Comment: I am so sorry, the region should be |w|≥1